# Refresh page on deadlock in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, refresh, deadlock

I have an exception handling in my application very similar to this solution: 
http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html

There is a nasty bug in my app where it is possible for the sql to deadlock with an other process. This happens rarely (1-2 requests fail daily because of this), but it still happens.

How can I automatically refresh the page on sql deadlock (and hide the error this way from the end user on get requests)?

Can I do it in the Application_Error function? Or in the overridden OnException in HandleErrorAttribute?

EDIT:

I mocked up some code in the BaseController I created:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
    SqlException sex = ex as SqlException;

    if (sex != null && sex.Number == 1205)
    {
       Log.Error("Transaction deadlocked with the following exception:");
       Log.Exception(sex);

       //I need to write the logic that refreshes the page here.
    }
    else
    {
       Log.Error("Application error with the following exception:");
       Log.Exception(ex);
    }

    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

I need help on the refresh part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would deal with it by overriding the OnException() method of the controller.  It would be best if you inherit all your controllers from a custom base one in which the override is done to maintain uniformity and DRYness of the solution.

Comment: So writing the logic which refreshes the page in the OnException() function is DRY. Can you help me write the actual logic?

Comment: That is highly dependent on your application. But one general pattern is to include the path of the view in the viewmodel against which the view is typed and have the OnException redirect to that url. This should refresh the view.

Comment: The problem was that the current URL is the same where I want to redirect. But a Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

just add bellow code, before `base.OnException(filterContext);`

```
// Stop any other exception handlers from running
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
```